# How can i remove T and Z from this Jsonarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
var data = [
{
    "Id": 4,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-04T15:47:17Z"
},
{
    "Id": 5,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T15:53:24Z"
},
{
    "Id": 6,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T18:59:32Z"
},
{
    "Id": 7,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T20:05:39Z"
}
]
```

I want above jsonaaray look like below structure. Without using loop will be best for me. 
I want the easiest one which help me to improve my experience.
 Would you please suggest me how can i solve this?

```
var data = [
{
    "Id": 4,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-04 15:47:17"
},
{
    "Id": 5,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05 15:53:24"
},
{
    "Id": 6,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05 18:59:32"
},
{
    "Id": 7,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05 20:05:39Z"
}
]
```

Comment: check this [Javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), try `var dateObj = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');`, then  `dateObj .toLocaleString()`

Comment: Whithout loop? `for (var i=.....) {}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the function `forEach` would be the cleanest way.

```js
var data = [{    "Id": 4,    "Created_at": "2017-11-04T15:47:17Z"},{    "Id": 5,    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T15:53:24Z"},{    "Id": 6,    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T18:59:32Z"},{    "Id": 7,    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T20:05:39Z"}];

data.forEach(d => d.Created_at = d.Created_at.replace('T', " ").replace("Z", ""));
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks, much better choice than a map, better to change in situ than to create a new array

Comment: Unless you need immutability

Comment: @wizloc yes, however the OP wants to modify the original array.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there is a better date related solution, but you could easily use map() to loop through and remove the letters

```
data.map(item => ({ Id: item.Id, Created_at: item.Created_at.replace(/T/g,' ').replace(/Z/g, '')}))
```

```js
var data = [
{
    "Id": 4,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-04T15:47:17Z"
},
{
    "Id": 5,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T15:53:24Z"
},
{
    "Id": 6,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T18:59:32Z"
},
{
    "Id": 7,
    "Created_at": "2017-11-05T20:05:39Z"
}
]

console.log(data.map(item => ({ Id: item.Id, Created_at: item.Created_at.replace(/T/g,' ').replace(/Z/g, '')})))
```

Comment: The function `map` is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: @Ele Unnecessary how? It seems a lot cleaner and straight-forward to me. It's pretty much exactly the kind of thing map was made for: map one set of values to another.

Comment: The OP wants to modify the original array.

Comment: he actually doesnt specify for or against that

Comment: Sure, then they can set the `data` variable back again. It accomplishes the same result, with `map` having the additional benefit of being able to preserve the original array if needed

Answer (score 1):

This will be the cleanest way:

```
data.map(obj => {
  return { Id: obj.Id, Created_at: obj.Created_at.slice(0, -1) }
})
```